# Is this a valid description of the Riemann Zeta function?

Tags: riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

Where a and x are real numbers
$$\zeta(a-ix)=2^{a-ix}*\pi*\gamma(1-a+ix)*\sin(\frac{\pi}2*(a-ix))*\zeta(1-a+ix)$$

I got it from wolfram alfa I just wanted to make sure it was valid.For all values of a and x.

fixed
$$ζ(s)=2^{s}π^{s−1}*sin(\frac{πs}2) Γ(1−s) ζ(1−s)$$

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: This is essentially the reflection formula. Just correct $\sin$ to $\cos$ with $\sin(x-\pi/2)=\cos(x)$. See (13) of: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html

Comment: Sure. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=zeta(a-ix).  Near the bottom, under functions.

Comment: You've missed the exponent of $\pi$ and the last $-ix$ should be $+ix$. Other than that, it's precisely the reflection formula, as Antinous mentions.

Comment: [The functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#The_functional_equation) $$\zeta(s) = 2^s\pi^{s-1}\ \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\ \Gamma(1-s)\ \zeta(1-s)$$

Answer (score 0):

According to a number of people in the comments,
as well as at a number of links

mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html

wolframalpha.com/input/?i=zeta(a-ix)

$$ζ(s)=2^{s}π^{s−1}*sin(\frac{πs}2) Γ(1−s) ζ(1−s)$$
Where s is a complex number.
Is a valid description of the Riemann Zeta function.

Comment: $\zeta(s)$ is not the only meromorphic function satisfying this functional equation

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. You lost me at meromorphic. If you are more informed about the topic please fell free to answer the question in more detail.

Comment: $\zeta(s)$ is not the only one solution to the functional equation $F(s) = \chi(s) F(1-s)$ with $\chi(s) = 2^{s}π^{s−1} sin(\frac{\pi s}2)\Gamma(1−s) $

Comment: Meromorphic means being the quotient of two analytic functions. $\zeta(s) = \frac{(s-1) \zeta(s)}{s-1}$ where both $(s-1) \zeta(s)$ and $s-1$ are analytic

Comment: cool, I will have to look into that further.Where can I go to do so

Comment: There are many books and courses on the Riemann zeta function and complex analysis.